# How do I create a Word VBA personal VBA code library as I have done in Microsoft Excel..?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

How do I create a Word VBA personal code library as I have done in Microsoft Excel..? I had this working, but today it broke and I cannot make it work again. I originally did this because my Normal.dot file blew up and I lost all my macros. I found a blog post that described how to do it, but I cannot find my way back there. I've Google this extensively, but not found a solution.

There are some twists & turns here, as described below...

In Microsoft Excel, one can easily create a "code library project". This is simply a standard XLSB file with VBA modules in it, saved in the `..\Excel\STARTUP` folder alongside the `PERSONAL.XLSB` file.

When the VBA editor is open in any other XLSX/B file, the modules in the code library file are *always* visible. And thre's not a requirement to create a VBA project reference to see them. The library modules can be natively edited as if they were an integral part of any other file, *without requiring the library file to be open in another window to do so*, as shown in the picture...

[image]

However...in Microsoft Word, it seems to work differently, and...strangely. If the same is done: create a DOCM file with custom code modules, and save it in the `..\Word\Startup\` folder, those modules are *not visible in the VBA Project Explorer*.

Following along the chain of logic from Excel to Word, and do as others have done...save the DOCM as a DOTM instead, and save it in the `..\Templates` folder with the Normal.dotm file. Still, it is not visible in Project Explorer.

It's not until Normal.dotm is opened for editing and the library DOTM is added as a VBA Project Reference that it finally appears in the Project Explorer, but only while Normal is open. Plus...it opens the code library file for editing in another window..! If Normal is saved with that reference, and a new document is created from it, the library code cannot be edited and displays the error "project is unviewable"...

[image]

It's not until the library DOTM file is opened for editing in a *second* window that it's code becomes editable, and it does so in all Word VBA windows on all documents at the same time.

There is one glimmer of hope: if I create a new blank DOC from the library DOTM instead of Normal.DOTM, it works..! Any document created from the library retains a link to the code modules there, including any new or edited ones, and they can be edited natively right there in the Project Explorer. And this includes the code modules in Normal.DOTM too.

It seems the "editability" is one way: documents created from any other template can see & edit both their own code and those in Normal.DOTM, but not the other way around: documents created from Normal.DOTM can only see their own code.

How can this connection be made two-way for all documents, regardless of what template they were created from..??

I've been trying to wrap my head around the possibility it may be a security/malware issue, but I can't come up with one. If macros are already enabled in the Trust settings, malware is already 99% on the way to controlling a machine anyways. The only step left is enabling VBIDE.

Comment: Basically, that's how it works in Word. There is no other way. Normal.dotm is the only "universal" macro "container". Other add-in template projects need to be referenced to be used by other code. In order to change the code, the templates need to be opened explicitly. What is always available in Word from add-in templates are user-oriented things such as: Ribbon customizations, keyboard shortcuts, building blocks. Excel and Word are very different in how templates are used. For example, Word documents maintain a link to the template from which they were created - not the case with Excel.

Comment: Thanks. I only use Word VBA a fraction of the time compared to the work I do in Access VBA & Excel VBA, so some of this is new ground for me. I spent a chunk-o-time nosing around the objects in the Locals window yesterday and discovered Building Blocks for the first time. I also found that link between a document and its template, and I was trying to find a programmatic way to create such a link between a document & a template that it did *not* originate from, but no dice yet.

Comment: Ah, that's no problem: `Document.AttachedTemplate = filePathToTemplate`

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to experiment with that, but tomorrow... Thanks..!

Answer (score 3):

[A very similar question on Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-customize/location-for-a-users-default-macros-in-word/dda2bbaa-43e8-477b-a483-8d9c147e1492?db=5):

> Is there a startup or template file in Words that allows one to store "personal macros", i.e. macros that one wants to have always available while editing documents (I am seeking the equivalent to the PERSONAL.XLSB file in Excel, where I can store macros that then are available in all sheets that I open).

And the solution given:

> Word uses the default template Normal.dotm for this purpose. Macros stored in Normal.dotm will be available in all documents. Apart from that, Normal.dotm also serves as the default document template, and it also stores the user's formatted AutoCorrect entries.
>
> Just like Personal.xlsb, Normal.dotm doesn't exist in a clean new installation, but it will be created when needed.
>
> The location for Normal.dotm is
>
> `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`
>
> AppData is a hidden folder, so you must display hidden files and folders in order to see it in Windows Explorer.

[Similar questions](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/normaldotx-and-similar/42378d7b-0511-41ae-b105-569257e26803?db=5) (also on answers.microsoft.com) have been offered same type of solution.

> Macros that should be globally available can be stored in Normal.dotm or in a template located in the Startup folder for Word. See also:

And:

> In Word, personal settings (those that aren't stored in the Registry) are stored in the Normal template, Normal.dotm. When you change and save settings or create macros, they are automatically saved in Normal.dotm unless you choose to save them in another template. Normal.dotm is automatically loaded when you start Word, and new Blank Documents are based on Normal.dotm.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of how Word uses the Normal.dotm file. The reason I'm trying to create a library is that I lost all my macros when Normal.dotm blew up about two weeks ago. I Googled the issue and found a blog entry that described how to do what I seek, but now I cannot find my way back to that page. There have been further developments. I discovered that if I create a new document based on my library DOTM file, all the code there is vilible, PLUS all the code in Normal.DOTM. Somehow when the DOTM is copied into a new DOCX, the link to its code is retained.

Comment: Pardon, but I can't parse what you're trying to say. The answer is to use Normal.dotm.  If you're concerned about losing data, then you should make periodic back-ups of that (and any other sensitive data). One other possible solution would be to create a Word Add-In, but if it's anything like PowerPoint it's nothing like Excel, and is a whole lot of pain-in-the-ass. Best to just use Normal.dotm

Comment: Yes, I'm considering the Add-In route. There are a number of things I'd like to do in the IDE, such as code formatting, simple source control, and timer-based auto-save.

Comment: Source control would be a Godsend. The only way I've managed to do that in the past is to create a routine that programmatically exports all Modules to a directory which contains a Git repository. I had a python script then that would rebuild the .ppam Add-In from that repo. It's not ideal, but it was better than nothing. That was a few years ago. Now, I think I'd just do the add-in in Visual Studio which has all of those features built-in.

Comment: Yep. I read the directions for making it work with GIT and I was like, whaaaaaat? There has to be a better way. My goal is simple SC that spans all programs. Basically any software that has a VBA window, that being Office and even non-MS products like Autocad and Corel Draw. They could all share code. I hope. =-)